# Can I use droid as a character class in my game?

Tags: intellectual-property, trademark

We all know Droid is trademarked by Lucasfilms but I wanted to use it as a character class for my game.

The droid class in my game is also a robot, but it looks nothing like the droids on Lucasfilms. The only similarity is they are both a type of robot.

Could I be sued for using the Droid name in my game?

When I say character classes, something like: Humans, Elfs, Droids... (and maybe Androids too?)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can and will be sued.

The word is trademarked irrespective of the meaning or context you give it (with a few exceptions, such as referring to Lucas' own works in a work of fiction or non-fiction).

Verizon had to licence use of the name from Lucasarts when they used it for the name of their phone. If you use it in a game that you intend to distribute, you can expect contact from Disney's lawyers.

Comment: Trademarks are context sensitive. They are relative to listed classes of goods or services. Presumably you could make and sell Droid toilet paper (as long as there were not images of robots or phones on them). For example there is an trademark for ACME owned by a company that makes bookmarks and a completely separate ACME trademark for a company that makes cinematic cameras, and one for a tea company.

Comment: So in my case, would it be considered the same classes of goods and services? A movie/story character race vs a game character race?

Comment: How many games do you think have been made by Lucasarts? Both computer games and tabletop?

Comment: @GeorgeWhite That's fine. Are you going to answer every question about trademarks to say whether they are or aren't at risk of being sued? Especially in this case where they most definitely are. Are you a lawyer? The best way to handle trademarks if you don't have the wherewithall to fight a case is to assume that a TM will affect you.

Comment: Actually, @GeorgeWhite are you going to accept the liability when majidarif gets sued? Because that trademark certainly applies in the context majidarif was asking about. The best assumption to make is that the trademark applies. If you want to debate it, then... that's actually up to you.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins - You are correct that what the OP would like to do is crazy.  I did not provide my information in the form of an answer to the question. I simply pointed out that the part of your answer where you say context is irrelevant is wrong. And gave examples.  It is very true that trademarks are rights specifis to product areas - i.e. context, I take it from your comments that providing information regarding anything legal is a very bad idea on this site unless one is a lawyer and is prepared to defend anyone who takes the information as legal advice.

Comment: @GeoffAtkins, Verizon may have had to license the term originally, but if they're paying a licensing fee now, they're getting scammed: LucasFilm's trademark on "Droid" as related to cell phones was abandoned in 2015.  That said, the OP's intended use is probably covered by one or more of the still-active trademarks, most likely the one for video-game software.